# Calculating Nested Sums

Tags: summation

I know that
$$
\sum^{n}_{k_p=0}  \sum_{k_{p-1}=0}^{k_p} ...\sum_{k_1=0}^{k_2}1 = {n+p\choose n} 
$$

Now I would like to calculate the closed-form solution for the following
$$
\sum^{n}_{k_p=1}  \sum_{k_{p-1}=1}^{k_p} ...\sum_{k_1=1}^{k_2}x_{k_1} = ?
$$

Where $x_i \in Z$.

Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: Perhaps you can come up with a comparison or a visualization about how the first result is obtained. Is there another mathematical problem that it provides an answer to? Perhaps a combinatorics problem?

Comment: I got the first result from this article https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL13/Butler/butler7.pdf

Comment: What is ${x_k}_1$?

Comment: $x_i$ is just an integer from a defined set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $\displaystyle\sum^{n}_{k_p=1}\sum_{k_{p-1}=1}^{k_p}\ldots\sum_{k_1=1}^{k_2}x_{k_1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}c_k x_k$, where, using the idea of [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), $$c_k=\#\{(k_2,\ldots,k_p):k\leqslant k_2\leqslant\ldots\leqslant k_p\leqslant n\}=\binom{n-k+p-1}{p-1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$\sum_{k=m}^{n} {k \choose m}={n+1 \choose m+1}$$
So $$\sum_{x=k_1}^{k_2} {x \choose k_1}={k_2+1 \choose k_1+1}$$

Contunue like this.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on your second statement?

Comment: I think ${x_k}_1$ is actually ${x \choose k_1}$, then my solution works.